# Sending video frames from OpenCV program to Samsung Android

Tags: android, opencv, video

Just wanted to know before I dive into this field.

Is it possible to send video frames from an opencv program on windows to a Samsung android tab and visualize it there?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: yes, you can transfer images and display them

Comment: images are just data, and isn't data being transfered from your computer to the Internet (and vice-versa) all the time? So yes, you can send a image from one device to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the opposite, sending a stream of images from Android to a C/OpenCV program on windows, quite some time ago. The maximum frame rate I got was only ~12FPS for 320x240 B/W images using a G1 over WiFi. I tested different thing like sending compressed images (JPEG) or raw pixels but that was the maximum I got. I assume the limiting factor was the processing speed of the G1 combined with the poor camera stack of Android 1.6. On more decent devices a higher frame rate shouldn't be a problem. But it should even work on a G1 with a more sophisticated approach.

Your direction should be easier because if you want to compress the transmitted images that happen on a fast windows machine and you don't have to deal with the phone’s camera. Just transmit the pixels from your C/C++ application over a socket to you Android app using a WiFi connection. You might, however, have to consider the machines/languages [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). You could also try to use streaming video (just like youtube). But that might require much more effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After processing, if you compress the frame to a bitmap, then you can send it to the device with WiFi. Split it up into chunks, send the chunks to the device, then reassemble the data on the device, create a image from the data, and display it in an imageview or something.